# Factorization of sum and difference of factorized coprimes

Tags: computational-complexity, prime-factorization

If I have the prime factors of two coprimes $a$ and $b$, is it possible to find the prime factors of $a + b$ and $a - b$ faster than a full factorization?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  a+b and a-b are each co-prime to each of a and b.  Therefore, you know that none of the prime factors of a or b is a factor of a+b or a-b.  Therefore, there is no need to test a+b or a-b for those factors.